# Why is the button compacted or off-screen in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, button

You know I have a question about why I have the "Add" button that way, it is practically as if it were leaving the activity, even the text "Add data ..." is also wrong because of this, I have to say that I'm still new to all this from the android studio, so anything could help me, I tried a lot but I couldn't fully show the button, only the part that you see in the image (I tried using LinearLayout as well)

[it's done like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WDw3.png)

[this is how I would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtO2q.png)

I add the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_degradado"
    tools:context=".NuevoPacienteActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/agregue_datos_del_paciente"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextRutPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_person_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/rutPa"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout10"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextNombrePa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_person_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/nombre"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout10"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout11"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextApellidoPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_person_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/apellidos"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout11"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout12"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout10"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmailPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_email_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/emailPa"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout12"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout11"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPhonePa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_phone_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/n_mero_de_celularPa"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout12"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextMotivoConsultaPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_phone_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/motivo_de_consulta"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonAgregarPa"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextDiagnosticoPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_phone_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/diagnostico"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonAgregarPa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/agregarPa"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add some padding to the parent ConstraintLayout,  or give maxHeight = "matchparent"

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Luckily `ConstraintLayout` works to flatten a views hierarchy. Meaning you should avoid giving control over to the `CardView` and have the `CardView` on the same level as `ConstraintLayout2`. Meaning use `CardView` as a pure view its just for show.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:elevation="11dp" <- If you want to keep the CardView elevated
        android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <!-- All your TextViews and EditTexts HERE-->
        
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp" <- Change to 0dp to fill space
    android:layout_height="0dp" <- Change to 0dp to fill space
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="-1dp" <- CardViews have inherent elevation you need to get rid of it or elevate everything else above it
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but this happens to me when applying your answer [link](https://ibb.co/xCR24RL) I tried to change to match parent in the CardView but got no better result [link](https://ibb.co/YPTbMn5) from what i understand the textview is not being placed inside the cardview, will there be a solution? Or a better method to have that kind of uniform white background?

Comment: Maybe try reversing the order in the xml. Put the CardView at the bottom of the xml and your ConstraintLayout with all the textviews and edits above it. But keep the constraints the same.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the same thing happens, it's like the content does not adapt to 5-inch screens, in superiors, as there is more space, everything falls well, but I don't know why it does not adapt

Comment: Can you repost what you have with the `CardView` and `ContraintLayout2` separated it should work if not with a little finagling.

Comment: here you can see what I have once put the cardview down [link](https://gist.github.com/CristCT/d1f64557020ceeac6b1f4b338b054a8d)

Comment: I have updated my answer, and marked the changes.

Comment: I updated the link code based on what you told me, although now the textview appears in the card, it still does not adapt well, because the button at the end and the textview at the beginning remain as off the screen, it only happens in cell phones with a 5-inch screen, Thanks for all the help

Comment: At this point you may have to much stuff on the screen, I tested it on my side and its pretty cramped. By adding a `ScrollView` as the parent of `ContraintLayout2` it will make it scrollable for smaller screens and will act normal for big of enough screens.